# Could not initialize class org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory on deploying to Servicemix

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-aop, apache-servicemix

I am making a functionality to add logging using Spring AOP using pointcuts.
I have added a folder spring in META-INF where I've kept beans.xml which has the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
       <!--<aop:include name="servicesLogger"/> 
   </aop:aspectj-autoproxy> -->

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator" />
<bean id="servicesLogger" class="com.app.services.core.logger.ServicesLogger"/>
```

The ServiceLogger class lies in a separate module that defines the pointcuts is as follows:

```
    package com.app.services.core.logger;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

    @Configurable("servicesLogger")
    @Aspect
    public final class ServicesLogger {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServicesLogger.class);

private ServicesLogger() {
    super();
}

@Before("execution(* *(..))")
public void beforeLog(JoinPoint point) {
    System.out.println(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
    log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
}

@After("execution(* *(..))")
public void afterLog(JoinPoint point) {
    System.out.println(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
    log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
}

@Around("execution(* *(..))")
public void aroundLog(JoinPoint point) {
        System.out.println(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
        log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
}

}
```

When I try to deploy the module containing the beans.xml file then the servicemix is unable to create the bean and throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory
```

I have tried installing the 4 jars:
- spring-core.jar
- spring-aop.jar
- aspectjrt.jar
- aspectjweaver.jar

into the servicemix as well as tried to provide it by putting them in lib folder of servicemix but to no avail.

Please guide me what I am missing in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should precise spring version.

Comment: In Spring 4 that class is in the `spring-aop` jar. Something else, not related, your around is broken you must use a `ProceedingJoinPoint` and always call `proceed()` on that and return the result of the call to `proceed()`. If your aspect would be applied all methods would return `null` and no underlying method would be called, basically  breaking your application!

Comment: i am using 
-spring-core 3.0.0.RELEASE
-spring-aop 3.0.0.RELEASE
-aspectjrt 1.6.11
-aspectjweaver 1.6.11

Could it be version issue??

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using spring 3 and yes the java file lies in spring-aop.jar. I have installed it into the karaf as well as kept it in lib folder but no success.

Comment: Your configuration is also flawed. `<aop:Aspectj-autoproxy/>` already takes care of the `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` and why is your aspect `@Configurable` I now where see you using that feature, remove it? Your issue lies probably with servicemix/karaf and on how they expose things to the class path.

Comment: thanks for the first part and yes
I also feel that the issue lies in the servicemix bundles which are not providing the required class but I am not able to find the reason to why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing some research on osgi/servicemix. Servicemix provides a feature spring-aspects that is a system bundle number 72.

```
    features:list
```

By this you will be able to view all the available features in karaf. Then to install the feature use the below command.

```
    features:install spring-aspects
```

After installing this now you have provided the aop capability to the servicemix. Now will need 2 more jars:

-aspectjrt.jar

-aspertjweaver.jar

If you have a later version of the aspectjweaver then you do not need the first one as it is a subset of aspectjweaver.jar

Just install the above jars into your karaf if they are available in your .m2

Use the below commands to install these:

```
    osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.11
    osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.6.11
```

An extra jar cglib.jar might be needed to be installed in some cases which can be done as follows:

```
    osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:cglib/cglib/2.1_3
```

I was able to resolve the dependencies and remove the above errors by doing this.

Hope this helps somebody else as well. :)